# Как получить из БД данные в формате JSON (СУБД PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

Каким образом из хранимой процедуры PostgreSQL вернуть результат в JSON `{ общее кол-во отфильтрованных записей, массив отфильтрованных записей}` ?

Comment: вам нужно сохранять Json в базе или значение из базы преобразовать в json?

Comment: Получить данные из базы и преобразовать в json.

Comment: а на каком языке вы работаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы вернуть какое-то значение лучше всего использовать [функции](http://postgresql.ru.net/docs/function.html), а не хранимые процедуры.

Как вариант, можно использовать один из [типов JSON](http://postgrespro.ru/doc/datatype-json.html) поддерживаемых PostgreSQL.